# I'm trying to scroll to the bottom of a list when it's updated, using Aurelia and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, aurelia

I'm displaying a list of items stored in an array, inside a scrollable div.

```
<div id="historybox" class = "overflow-auto row h-75 border border-primary">
  <div class="col">
    <ul>
      <li repeat.for="line of history">
        <strong>${line.label}</strong> : ${line.text}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want it so that when a new item is add to the history array, the historybox div scrolls down to the bottom.

I tried adding an `@observable` tag to the variable and then adding the following method:

```
historyChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
  $('#historybox').scrollTop($('#historybox')[0]?.scrollHeight ?? 0);
}
```

This does indeed scroll the list down when a new item is added. But it only scrolls it to the second-last item in the list rather than the last.

I suspect this is because this `historyChanged` function runs after the history list is changed but before the page is actually updated. Adding a 100 millisecond delay before calling `scrollTop` seems to fix it, but that seems like a less than ideal solution. So I'm wondering what the "correct" way to do this is.

Comment: [Yes it does.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

But yeah I probably should use ``$('#historybox').prop('scrollHeight')``. Although that doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: I stand corrected - that's a nice little bit of syntactic sugar I didn't know about :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to do some dynamically "scroll to bottom" some time ago.
You can put that in a callback or something.
I did that with pure JavaScript.

```
// Pin scroll to bottom
document.getElementById('historybox').scrollTop = document.getElementById('historybox').scrollHeight
```

As you can see it will set the scrollTop attribute to the value of the scrollHeight attribute, which is the bottom.

I'm just passing by in a little of a hurry, I hope it helps, and if that's not what you want let me know and I can try to help you further later.

Comment: That does indeed scroll the box to the bottom, but I still need to figure out how to make it run after the list item is added to the page rather than before.

Comment: As I've said you can use that in the callback of a function, or in a Hook or something.
I've used it with React so I just put that on a useEffect Hook. jQuery might have something or you can just write as a callback to your "add" function, or put the code in the end of the function.
Do you know what a callback function is? If not, take a look at this.